# Cursor not showing

Tags: defold

As we develop a little game with defold (defold 1.2.102 | defold editor 2) we encountered the following problem:

When we start our game the window shows everything we built properly and there are no build errors or error console logs. However there is no cursor. Neither on the levelscreen of the game nor on one of the other monitors. We added a keypress input for testing the buttons and it worked properly, but the problem remains: Where is our mouse pointer? Do we have to add or adjust it somehow?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you running your game in fullscreen mode? Defold always hides the mouse pointer while running in fullscreen mode. You can add a game object with a sprite (or even better a gui box node) and let that follow the mouse coordinates and use it as a custom pointer for your game.

Comment: Yes we are using fullscreen. Thank you very much!